# «Да святится имя Твое» or «Да святится имя Твоё»?

Tags: произношение, буква-ё

A colleague of mine asked me to record the text of the prayer for her band to learn. I want to make sure I do it right.

In the words «да святится имя Твое» — is the last letter е or ё?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The liturgical language of Russian Orthodox Church is not Russian but [Church Slavonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_Slavonic_language). Church Slavonic is a codified version of [Old Church Slavonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Church_Slavonic), which technically is not even a direct ancestor of Russian but noticeably [influenced](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%8B) Russian.

In Church Slavonic there's no such thing like "ё". Technically «да святится имя Твое» is a valid Russian phrase and the same time a valid Old Church Slavonic. In the latter case it's pronounced with stressed `е`. If you say it in Russian it's perfectly valid to say "твоё".

Traditionally though it's pronounced as 'твое' by people close to church but not necessarily even knowing Church Slavonic.

Comment: A valid Old Church Slavonic phrase is actually "да свѧтитъ сѧ имѧ Твоѥ" with those nasalised [e]'s and a yer.

Comment: @YellowSky true for Old Church Slavonic, in Church Slavonic nasals were gone.

Answer (score 7):

In the church they traditionally pronounce it with "е": https://youtu.be/-cueR_3HVR0 (1:25).

By the way, Wikipedia has an [entry](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88) for this. There you can find several versions of the text (from ancient to modern Russian) with е/ё explicitly marked.